# Initialising 'double' with an expression of incompatible type 'id'

Tags: objective-c, ios, initialization

Im trying to assign a value to a double, using the following code:

```
double distanceFormat = [self.runsArray[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"runDistance"];
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
Initialising 'double' with an expression of incompatible type 'id'
```

However, I know the value is a double! Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is self.runsArray an array of Dictionaries? I imagine you just need to add doubleValue to the end

Comment: Yes, It works with strings. I just cant get xcode to believe me that there is a double in there!

Comment: Just try [[self.runsArray[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"runDistance"] doubleValue];

Comment: If it's an array of dictionaries there **cannot** be a double there as `NSDictionary` cannot store doubles as values. Either it is storing `NSNumber`s, in which case @rooster117 suggestion is your solution, or you have some problems somewhere else. Why do you think it has doubles there?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Could you try with:

```
double distanceFormat = [[self.runsArray[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"runDistance"] doubleValue];
```

If you're sure it is double I think it would work.

Answer (score 7):

Use NSNumber

```
NSNumber *mynumber = [somedictionary valueForKey:@"runDistance"];
```

Once you have the nsnumber, you can convert it into whatever you want, f.ex :

```
int i = [mynumber intValue];
```